# How can I set up VSCode to put curly braces on the same line?

Tags: visual-studio-code

By default this

```
{path: '/post/:postId', component: Post},
```

are converting to this

```
{
    path: '/post/:postId',
    component: Post
},
```

How can I disable this behavior?

UPD. I am coding in JavaScript, last time in vuejs with vetur plugin

UPD2. Code expample.

```
// before
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Home },
    { path: '/about', component: About },
    { path: '/todo', component: Todo },
  ]
})
// after formatting (curly braces are moved on new line)
export default new Router({
    routes: [{
            path: '/',
            component: Home
        },
        {
            path: '/about',
            component: About
        },
        {
            path: '/todo',
            component: Todo
        },
    ]
})
```

UPD 3. Maybe Prettier will be useful to solve this task?

UPD 4. In my case, the problem was in the additional plugin for formatting. Beautify was installed as the default option for formatting and all settings for vscode formatter was not working.

The solution is set vscode formatter or prettier by default.

```
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
},
```

Thanks all. Especially for maven87.

Comment: The latter is a pretty standard convention across the languages I've used. If other people are going to be reading your code, you might want to stick with convention.

Comment: @Adrian, I agree this is important. But this question about another problem.

Comment: which language you are coding into?

Comment: JavaScript, last time in vuejs with vetur plugin

Comment: can you put more code. so we can debug properly? like you are using array or function or something

Comment: @Ravi, I've added code example in question

Comment: Aren't these contrary requirements: Leaving the first curly braces for  `new Router( { ... })` on different lines. And for each children in the collection, put the curly braces on the same line?

Comment: @MartinBackasch, In this case, I need format code to tab instead of spaces and live this code on the same line "{ path: '/', component: Home }". For example, prettier can do that due to this playground https://prettier.io/playground/.

Comment: Could you share a minimum reproducible example of your problem and settings/extensions you use? Can't really reproduce this on my end, the objects are never chopped down and left as-is.

Comment: I have the exact same issue when defining routes in vuejs. I have just continued to put up with manually reformatting the lines when the file is edited/reformatted. Maybe an override to disable formatting for individual files would be useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The settings you are looking for are:

```
{
  // Defines whether an open brace is put onto a new line for control blocks or not.
  "javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": false,

  // Defines whether an open brace is put onto a new line for functions or not.
  "javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": false
}
```

Please refer to the [User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) article. It covers similar settings for other languages too.

If that doesn't provide enough control you may also choose to use [Beautify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify)
and specify a `.jsbeautifyrc`

with a setting for brace style as follows:

```
{
   "js": {
       "brace_style": "collapse,preserve-inline"
    }
}
```

Please refer to [this](https://github.com/HookyQR/VSCodeBeautify/blob/master/Settings.md) to see all possible values.

**UPDATE**

It was pointed out that there is another degree of control where if you would like to change the formatter completely, you do so by installing the correct VS Code plugin and then configuring the appropriate formatter (see [User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) article). For example:

```
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
}
```

In this case the formatter being used is [Prettier - Code formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)

Comment: What about for json object literals? They're neither control blocks nor functions.

Comment: In my case, the problem was in the additional plugin for formatting. Beautify was installed as the default option for formatting and all settings for vscode formatter was not working. 

The solution is set vscode formatter or prettier by default.
You let me get this idea. Change your answer and I mark it as solution.

Comment: @karmakaze for the beautify plugin you can use the beautify.language setting and specify that js maps to javascript and json. You can view their [Readme](https://github.com/HookyQR/VSCodeBeautify/blob/master/README.md) for more information

Answer (score 1):

In VS Code go to settings:
"File->Preferences->Settings"

In settings search "curly".
It will search below settings, unckeck them and verify if it works as expected.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKEj1.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was in the additional plugin for formatting. Beautify was installed as the default option for formatting and all settings for vscode formatter was not working.

The solution is set vscode formatter or prettier by default.

```
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
},
```